# why animate method in jquery supports div with fixed poition but not div with static position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Animate method of jquery works on div with fixed position but not on div with static position .Why is it so. Although i know  the reason for relative and absolute position.But cant understand why is it for fixed position

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery animate **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

> Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible effect on elements if their  position style property is static, which it is by default

Definition for `fixed` position

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Sir i want to know why is it so?if it can be applied on fixed position then what is the significance of fixed position when its position can be changed by animate method

Comment: A fixed position element is positioned relative to the **viewport**, or the browser window itself. The **viewport** doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled, creating an effect a bit like the old school "frames" days.